# Having trouble with constructors and user-input

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, user-input

I'm working on a little project, but I'm having trouble. It has to do with creating classes, constructors, etc. For the class, all data fields have to be private. I must also have two constructors, one default and one parameterized. Here's the class:

```
public class PetInfo {

    private String petName = "na";
    private boolean petType = true;
    private String petBreed = "na";
    private double petAge = 0;
    private double petWeight = 0;
    private String ownerName = "na";

    public PetInfo(){}

    public PetInfo(String name, boolean type, String breed, double age, double weight, String owner){
        this.petName = name;
        this.petType = type;
        this.petBreed = breed;
        this.petAge = age;
        this.petWeight = weight;
        this.ownerName = owner;
    }

    public String getName (){
        return petName;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        petName = name;
    }

    public boolean getType(){
        return petType;
    }

    public void setType(boolean type){
        petType = type;
    }

    public String getBreed(){
        return petBreed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed){
        petBreed = breed;
    }

    public double getAge(){
        return petAge;
    }

    public void setAge(double age){
        petAge = age;
    }

    public double getWeight(){
        return petWeight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight){
        petWeight = weight;
    }

    public String getOwner(){
        return ownerName;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner){
        ownerName = owner;
    }
}
```

Here is what I have in my main function:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pp1_C00019540 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PetInfo[] info = new PetInfo[5];
        collectInfo(info);
    }
    public static void collectInfo(PetInfo[] info){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < info.length;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter pet name: "); 
        }
    }
}
```

So it prints "Enter pet name: ", but it won't let me input a name. I tried to do:

```
    info[i] = new PetInfo(input.nextLine());
```

But it tells me "constructor PetInfo.PetInfo(String, boolean, String, double,double, String) is not applicable. Actual and formal arguments differ in length." Is there something wrong with my class that I'm not catching? I tested it and it seemed to work correctly.

And I'm not looking for a definite answer, I could more than likely figure it out myself. I'm just not sure what's going on, especially when it seemed to me like this would work when I passed the constructor the correct parameters.

Comment: It's pretty simple. There's no `PetInfo` constructor that expect a single `String` argument.

Comment: "it tells me "constructor PetInfo.PetInfo(String, boolean, String, double,double, String) is not applicable" - right because you're passing to the constructor only one string: `new PetInfo(input.nextLine())`

Comment: @shmosel I haven't worked with constructors that have more than one argument. So even though I passed String in the parameterized constructor, I still have to create a specific PetInfo constructor that expects the one argument? I'm assuming this would work the same for the boolean and double arguments too?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. If you want to assign each field individually, you can use the zero-arg constructor and then call the setters. Or you can collect everything in variables and pass them all into the multi-arg constructor. Or you can create additional constructors. It's up to you.

Comment: @shmosel I must have a default constructor and a parameterized constructor, and a call to new must result in all class data members being initialized. So it looks like I need to use the multi-argument constructor

Comment: Yes, you must either declare a constructor that accepts 1 argument, or fill in the arguments for the other parameters in your current constructor. Java does not support optional parameters. If you declare parameters, you must specify arguments. You currently don't have a `PetInfo(String)` constructor. As for the default constructor (more specifically, the [nullary constructor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullary_constructor) - it's only a default constructor if you don't declare it & don't declare any other constructors), it's not needed unless you need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your code is trying to call the `PetInfo` constructor that takes a single string as input. But based on the code you have, no such constructor exists. You just have the large multi-parameter constructor for `PetInfo`. You need to call the scanner for input several times before you call the constructor. See the code below:

```
private static void collectInfo(PetInfo[] info) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter pet name: ");
            String petName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter pet type: ");
            boolean petType = input.nextBoolean();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter pet breed: ");
            String petBreed = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter pet age: ");
            double petAge = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter pet weight: ");
            double petWeight = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter pet owner: ");
            String petOwner = input.nextLine();
            info[i] = new PetInfo(petName, petType, petBreed, petAge, petWeight, petOwner);
        }
    }
    finally {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Hopefully the code above gives you a good illustration of what I'm talking about. Also, don't forget to call `input.nextLine()` after calls to `nextBoolean()` and `nextDouble()`. Lastly, don't forget to close your `input` scanner to avoid a resource leak.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great! was explaining in the comments to OP about this, too lazy to type. Good job!

Comment: @Saramali Thanks for the laugh. :-)

Comment: I'm an idiot. This makes perfect sense. Thanks @Saramali, thanks @entpnerd! I really do appreciate the help

Comment: @ANewProgrammer No you're not. You're a new programmer. :-) Keep working at it. Keep posting. Don't let the turkeys get you down. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's simple, when you input using scanner. It takes input in a string, since there is no such constructor which takes string as a parameter it is giving you an error.

You need to take the input from scanner in respective datatypes, store them in variables and then call the constructor. I think what you are trying to do is to call the constructor while taking comma separated input from the scanner, that's not possible.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and that makes sense. But how do I then add those variables to the array?

Comment: You create an object of pet info. Firstly you should change the name. The class name should be Pet and the array name should be myPets something like that. Anyhow, you create an object using the constructor and then you can add that object in the array.

Comment: I hope you understood

Comment: So are you saying that in the for loop, I basically store the input in variables, then make another object using the constructor?

Comment: No, in the for loop you can take inputs in respective variables, create an object and add that object in the array. All this will be one iteration of a loop.

Comment: the latest answer, is what I was saying!